# Parse PFInstallation query to delete entries (many entries)

Tags: parse-platform

hi guys i have a question about the PFInstallation Query,

i really need to delete some entries in PFInstallation, about 400.000, yeah right a lot entries,  via iOS sdk is not possibile, 
and via console is like a suicide because i can delete only 100 elements at the time.

Before deleting i need to make a query to delete only the entries with my "appVersion" start with "3."

Any idea about the approach?

i know object c but no other language is for me familiar.

EDIT:
I have found a solution, not the best one but a solution. Export the class in JSON, remove from the JSON the installation before version 3.X reimport the JSON in PARSE as a Installation class... not clean, not code solution, but work and for the moment is enough... :-)

Comment: query.limit can be set to 1000, but 400 of those will result in a timeout.  Try a scheduled job that runs frequently and deletes 1k (for simplicity) at a time.

Comment: You can't delete PFInstallation object via SDK.

Comment: Do you get errors when you try to delete the installation via the SDK? It might be that it requires could code, or more specifically the master key...

Comment: Yes i get error, and i need to use cloud code, but i don't know how, that's the point :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you only know obj-c then it's probably easiest to create a new app and write some code to generate a `PFQuery` and batch through all the installations in groups of 1000. Build up a list of all of the ones you want deleted and then batch through them in groups of 1000 calling `deleteAllInBackground:` (on `PFObject`).

You can't use the SDK for that, so you need to use the REST interface and specify the master key in the header (instead of the REST client key).

Ideally this would be done in javascript as a cloud code job specified to use the master key (untested) so you avoid all of the network latency, you can then also use `.each` on the query to simplify the installation batching.

Comment: Unfortunately is not possible query PFInstallation via SDK

Comment: Why not? `PFInstallation` has a `query` method

Comment: Because give me this error

    error = "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.";
    originalError = "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)\"";